# Adding a managed dependency to Play 2 app

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I want to add Jersey-client to my Play 2 app using **SBT**.

So, I added the dependency into my `ApplicationBuild.scala` file as follows:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "wealcome-webapp"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-client" % "1.16"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
  )

}
```

So, in command-line I make :  `play reload update`.

Thus, I expect to find Jersey's jars file into `play-2.1-RC1/repository/local`.
However, I find jars into `play-2.1-RC1/repository/cache`.

What should I do to make automatically the dependency goes into the **local** folder in order to expect my app to compile?

Is it normal to find jars file into the **cache** folder? What is exactly the role of cache?

Comment: Have you check in your ~/.ivy, the shared local repository?

Comment: @Julien Lafont In fact, if I well figure out, play 2 initializes a local ivy repository in its own folder: play-2.1-RC1/repository/local, doesn't it?   Further, I have only a "cache" folder at this path: ~/.ivy2/cache

Comment: Maybe, I don't know very well this part of the framework. But with this build.scala, it should work. Have you an error when you compile you app? Have you tried "play dependencies" to see what happened?

Comment: I didn't know this command (I'm new to Play), but I"ve just run it and it displays that application can resolve the Jersey dependency . But when I make a simple import com.sun.jersey... in any controller, it doesn't find jersey. I really believe that I misunderstood the concept of "cache" and "local" folder within Play installation folder.

Comment: The error is thrown by Play or by your IDE ?

Comment: I've just succeed...Indeed, `play idea` had to be run in order to update source within intelliJ. Jars were copied to `myApp/lib_managed/jars`. I still don't understand the role of the play-2.1-RC1/repository/local folder ...

Comment: @nico_ekito Just for the comprehension, it matters :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an IDE make sure to run `play eclipsify` or `play idea` after making changes to your dependencies. Afterwards refreshing the project may be necessary. Then the class paths for the project files will be updated appropriately. Only SBT will be aware of your changes before you do this.